# Error in namespaces

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

I have recently created an .edmx file in my ASP .NET MVC4 application, and later on i have added a stored procedure and so I did a function import using Entity Framework 4.0.0.0 , but eventually an error pops out as

> The type or namespaces Core does not exist in the namespace System.Data.Entity

The same setup is been executed on my colleague's system, but the same error doesn't occur at his system.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EF 6 you have to include namespace `System.Data.Entity.Core`.

See [**here**](http://forums.asp.net/t/1977957.aspx?The%20type%20or%20namespace%20name%20Core%20does%20not%20exist%20in%20namespace%20System%20Data%20Entity%20) a similar [**question**](http://forums.asp.net/t/1977957.aspx?The%20type%20or%20namespace%20name%20Core%20does%20not%20exist%20in%20namespace%20System%20Data%20Entity%20) on [**forums.asp.net**](http://forums.asp.net/t/1977957.aspx?The%20type%20or%20namespace%20name%20Core%20does%20not%20exist%20in%20namespace%20System%20Data%20Entity%20)

[**HERE**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.core%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) is [`System.Data.Entity.Core`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.core%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) documentation.

Comment: Sir, I am using Entity Framework 5.0 and System.Data.Entity of version 4.0.0.0

Comment: see this on forums.asp.net OP solved by :``I uninstall and reinstall EF 5.0 and it works. We need EF 5.0``